# Accessing SignInMessage & Caching in identityserver3 UserService.GetProfileDataAsync

Tags: identityserver3

I have two questions:

1.
We have implemented an IdSrv3 that is multi-tenanted, at least up to a point. In essence we have many environments and at present we need a single IdSrv3 that serves them all. I am using the `SignInMessage.Tenant` to distinguish between them all and that works fine in the `AuthenticateLocalAsync` method on my custom user service. However I am unable to do this in the `GetProfileDataAsync` method. I am injecting the `OwinEnvironmentService` into my user service constructor and using that to get the `SignInMessage` and from that access the tenant, however this is always null, i.e.

UserService:

```
private readonly OwinEnvironmentService _env;

public UserService(OwinEnvironmentService env)
{
    _env = env;
}

public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var signInMessage = _env.Environment.GetSignInMessage();
        ...
    }
```

Is there any way to get at the `SignInMessage` tenant?

2.
Also how does claims caching work? In my startup, I am creating my userservice and setting the cache duration, i.e.:

```
factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService, UserService>();
factory.ConfigureUserServiceCache(TimeSpan.FromHours(12));
```

but how do I add my user claims? Do I need to do anything to add claims to the cache in `AuthenticateLocalAsyn`? How do I access the cached claims in `GetProfileDataAsync`?

Answer (score 0):

1) In the `GetProfileDataAsync` the subject claim should be sufficient to uniquely identify the user, and thus infer the tenant the user belongs to.

2) The caching is done as a decorator pattern, and the decorator does the caching. The cache is key'd by a combination of the subject and the scopes/claims requested.

Comment: Thanks, I have made the subject Environment Unique and it works fine. Plus I can see in the logging the cache being hit on user info